# How is the T-1000's appearance in Wayne's World explained?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Robert Patrick makes a cameo, apparently as the T-1000, in 1992's *Wayne's World*. Wayne is driving erratically when the T-1000 pulls him over. The T-1000 then approaches, removes its sunglasses and helmet, and (apparently) asks if Wayne has seen John Connor.

I understand that WW is a comedy, but is there an in-universe reason for this? Perhaps the cop isn't really the T-1000 (but Patrick is credited as such). Maybe WW and *Terminator 2* occur in the same universe and in the same general location.

Comment: Do you know that in part two, they see a T-Rex from "Jurassic Park"? There is no explanation for that either -it was there, because [it was funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)

Comment: I never really got into the JP movies. Obviously I was looking for an in-universe reason.

Comment: There isn't one - the Terminator or T-rex was there only because it was funny, not because they exist in-universe

Comment: It's a joke? In a comedy movie?

Comment: I thought that I deleted this manure pile of a question. Even Garth is probably disgusted with me.

Answer (score 12):

It's not explained. It was simply a 'bit' that they put in because they needed a joke to fill a scene. For the record, it was the studio's idea and Mike Myers was against it.

> *"There's two scenes I resisted that were sort of like, 'We need a joke here,' and in my Canadian 'What? You can't change things!' way, and one was the Terminator thing [Robert Patrick's cameo]. I was like, 'It's not funny, dude. It's not funny!' And people went shithouse over it. The other one was Lara Flynn Boyle hitting the car. The studio note was, 'We need something funny like a girl hitting a car on a bike.' And I was like, 'You can't dial up a joke like that! It has to be organic!' And every screening, people were like [mimics crowds rising to their feet and clapping in slow motion]."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Schwing! Mike Myers & Dana Carvey's 'Wayne's World' Reunion Recap](https://www.firstshowing.net/2013/schwing-mike-myers-dana-carveys-waynes-world-reunion-recap)</sup></sub>

Comment: Also, wasn't he nearby, doing some kind of promo for T2? I vaguely recall that being mentioned in an interview somewhere

Answer (score 4):

This is called "[The rule of funny](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny)", which TvTropes <sup>*</sup> defines as:

> The limit of the Willing Suspension of Disbelief for a given element is directly proportional to its funniness.
>   **Any violation of continuity, logic, physics, or common sense is permissible if the result gets enough of a laugh**.

Here is another example, from the second part of the movie:

This doesn't mean that in the Wayne's World are live dinosaurs or terminators - there are there just to make people laugh.

Here is another example:

During the fight Wayne swings his sword and cuts his pants to shreds (1:55). He looks down comically surprised, but two seconds later we can see that his pants are whole again. Yes, you can claim in-universe that he has magical, self-mending pants... or you can just get over it and laugh at it - it had no sense, but it was funny.

So don't look at any in-universe logical explanation - unless it is explicitly provided, there isn't any.

<sup>TvTropes warning!</sup>